# How to set Image in Window Title in XAML with MashAPPs.Metro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a window and want to set a Picture instead of the title text, but it only shows the String of the Image Namespace.

Code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow  x:Class="AdminControlCenter.View.MainView"
    ...
    Title="{Binding ImageViewModel.TitleBarImage}" Height="400" Width="600" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:MainViewModel}" Icon="{Binding ImageViewModel.Icon}">
```

Picture:

[image]

The Icon is shown Correctly and the Image is saved as a BitmapImage.

How can I set a Image in a window title instead of the normal text ?

Comment: Instead of that,why don't you store the image in app root folder and specify the path of image.

Comment: I make the program with the MVVM pattern

Comment: Window icon will be common to all windows right?So why are you coming for MVVM pattern?Just specify the path of the icon.

Comment: Right but I use the MVVM because i take the Icons from the Icon Pool on the Server and I reuse it often so its more convortable to make it with the mvvm I must only change one resource if something is changing etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it with the LeftWindow Command for the Image and Right Window For the Menu etc..

Code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
 <Controls:WindowCommands>
   <Image Source="{Binding ImageViewModel.TitleBarImage}"/>
 </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>

<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"/>
        <StackPanel Name="menuHolder" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Menu Name="MenuBar">
                <MenuItem Name="Options" Header="Options" >
                    <MenuItem Name="Settings" Header="Settings"/>
                    <MenuItem Name="Close" Header="Close"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </StackPanel>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

Picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using MahApps controls you need to do it like this:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.IconTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
              Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
              Margin="8 8 0 8"
              Background="Transparent"
              RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
              RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
            <Rectangle Fill="White">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_resource_group}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.IconTemplate>
```

You can use an Image control for a visual brush if you need to.